# Even numbers a list?

Tags: python, list

How do I create a list and only extract or search out the even numbers in that list?

Create a function `even_only(l)` that takes a list of integers as its only argument. The
function will return a new list containing all (and only) the elements of l which are evenly divisible by 2. The original list l shall remain unchanged.

For examples, `even_only([1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28])` should return `[6, 10, 28]`, and
`even_only([1, 4, 9, 16, 25])` should return `[4, 16]`.

Hint: Start by creating an empty list, and whenever you encounter an even number in it, add it to your list, then at the end, return your list.

Comment: the only thing i can think of is using a for loop in the function where the range of the input will be tested to see if it's divisible by 2 evenly.

Comment: You should look up modular division will help you a ton.  Also, the "create an empty list" is doable, but you may also look at filter.

Comment: @justin: This is totally fine. If you want more specific help, write some code and show us what does not work.

Comment: @g.d.d.c the performance on a list comprehension is better than that for a filter

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, **show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"By hand":

```
def even_only(lst):
    evens = []
    for number in lst:
        if is_even(number):
            evens.append(number)
    return evens
```

Pythonic:

```
def even_only(iter):
    return [x for x in iter if is_even(x)]
```

Since it's homework, you can fill in the `is_even` function.

Comment: it lacks a return evens in the first example

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm, i figured it out by hand =)

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way would be to do what you posted in a comment -- iterate through the input list to find digits evenly divisible by 2, and add them to the return list if so.

The [`list.append(x)`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) function will help you add an item to a list.

Also as mentioned, look at using the [modulo](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operation to determine if a number is divisible by 2...

Comment: any idea on how to use range of a list when it only accepts integers?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this (as a beginner) is probably a comprehension list. Since this is a homework, I won't do it for you, but here is the syntax :

```
[x for x in your_list if (your condition)]
```

You just have to replace (your condition) with what fits well (basically, exactly what you described).

P.S. I know some people may say comprehension lists are a bit advanced for a beginner, but I think it is not a concept too hard to catch and extremely useful.

Comment: getting to know a `for` loop would be much more helpful to him, given that a for loop exists in almost any programming language, which is not the case of list comprehensions.

Comment: I have to wonder--do you really think someone in CS101 who doesn't know how to tell even from odd should be going near list comprehensions?  It's giving a stick of dynamite to someone who isn't yet clear on the purpose of a wick.

Comment: Of course he must know what a for loop is, that doesn't mean he has to  skip comprehension lists. They aren't hard at all to understand, they are extremely common in Python code, etc. And because it doesn't exist in every programming language doesn't mean it should be learned last.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I have no idea what CS101 is (I am not a computer science student, nor an American) and **as a beginner**, I can say that, from my own experience, there's no point to postpone the learning of comprehension lists. If my post isn't useful for the OP, it's going to be useful for someone else who is learning and stumbles upon this question.

Comment: If the OP doesn't understand loops and conditionals, then he definitely should not be learning list comprehensions yet.  They're a concise syntax tightly combining the concepts of looping, conditionals and arrays.  If you don't understand those, you won't understand list comprehensions.  An intro-to-programming (first or second semester) student shouldn't be learning list comprehensions at all, or anything else that's very tightly tied to a particular language.

Comment: I totally understand your point, OP is an absolute beginner and comprehension list may be hard to understand right now, but if he is dedicated enough to programming, he should easily understand the concept in a few weeks max.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `filter` function to do this in a functional way:

```
>>> even_filter = lambda x: not x % 2
>>> result = filter(even_filter, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> assert result == [0, 2, 4]
```

Edit: updated with the correct parity of zero per Vincent's comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
>>> b = [i for i in a if i%2 ==0 ]
>>> b
[6, 10, 28]
>>> a
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
```

Comment: close but it only prints out the original list.

Comment: What only prints the original list?

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> even_only = lambda seq : [ x for x in seq if str(x)[-1] in "02468" ]
>>> even_only([1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28])
[6, 10, 28]
```

Comment: Hmmm...string conversion in an anonymous function that checks negative indicies....as a homework answer. Like that *wouldn't* have plaigerism written all over it! `:D +1`

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and used:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6] #whatever your list is, just a sample
evens=[x for x in list if np.mod(x,2)==0]
print evens
```

returns [2,4,6]

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit late.But whats given below, works fine for me:

```
def even_list(*args):  
    # Returns the even numbers in the list  
    return [x for x in args if (x % 2 == 0)] 



even_list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

for every element in list, if element of list modulo is 0 then number is even

```
initial_list =  [1,22,13,41,15,16,87]
even_list = [ x  for x in initial_list if  x % 2 == 0]
even_list
# [22, 16]
```